# Get integer array input from user in java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I need to get a series of integers from the user.
The user will not be prompted to enter the numbers. The input will be of the following form:

6

34 12 7 4 22 15

3

3 6 2

The first line signifies the number of integers in the second line.
I first tried to read the second line as a String and broke it to integers in the code using StringTokenizer. Sine this happens in my program a lot, it was time consuming and 
I needed to read them directly.
I remember in C++ it used to be fairly simple. The following code segment used to do the trick.

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
cin>>a[i];
```

To achieve this, I used the java.util.Scanner and my code looks as below:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);

for(x=0;x<2;x++){
    arraySize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    for(i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
        array[i] = src.nextInt();
}
```

In this case, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34 12 7 4 22 15"
```

I am open to suggestions and am not sticking to Scanner alone. If there is any other method to achieve this, I am game.

Comment: my guess is arraySize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); raises the exception ? am i right ?

Comment: StringTokenizer was THAT time consuming ? Did you profile it ?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the `homework` tag...

Comment: I suggested StringTokenizer in my answer after skimming and missing your mention of trying it already. I, too, am curious as to why you say StringTokenizer took a long time. Did it take a long time to run or did it take a long time to program? The former might betray problems on your system. The latter will betray problems in the design of your implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For future reference, here's a way to do it with the `Scanner` class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NumberReading {
    public static int [] readNumsFromCommandLine() {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine(); // throw away the newline.

        int [] numbers = new int[count];
        Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (numScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                numbers[i] = numScanner.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("You didn't provide enough numbers");
                break;
            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = readNumsFromCommandLine();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a second scanner?

Comment: For clarity and for basic validation. I wanted to make sure that the numbers the user were expecting were all on the second line and not spread about on different lines.

Answer (score 5):

You said you could use the following code in C++:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++) 
cin>>a[i];
```

If this is what you used in C++, why not just use this?

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
a[i] = input.nextInt();
```

Assuming that the scanner declaration was:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

From what I've seen, people are trying to write the entire program for you. But seeing as you stated you could solve this problem using the C++ code, I just converted the code to Java for you.

If you want the full code, here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create a new array. The user enters the size
        int[] array = new int[input.nextInt()];

        // Get the value of each element in the array
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = input.nextInt();

        /* Note that the user can type the following:
         * 6
         * 34 12 7 4 22 15
         * This will set the array to size 6
         * array[0] = 34;
         * array[1] = 12;
         * etc.
         */

    }

}
```

I realize that this response is years late, but I was searching for a different question when I ran across this. The answers here were very confusing to me until I realized this wasn't what I was looking for. Seeing as this still shows up on google, I decided to post this.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    int[] ints = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! I was looking for a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is "6 34 12 7 4 22 15 3 3 6 2" separated by *spaces* then it will be read all in one go by `br.readLine()`.  You can't pass "6 34 12 7 4 22 15 3 3 6 2" to `parseInt`, as you have seen.

For this case, I would recommend you call `String.split()` on the String returned by `br.readLine()`, and you will be left with an array of Strings which can be passed in turn to `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: I hadn't formatted my input in the question above. Actually, the input is in 4 different lines. I have updated the input above.

Comment: Well in that case I would ignore the *count* lines and use the .split() approach on the lines with actual data in.  Or use StringTokenizer.  There's unlikely to be a performance problem here - if there is then you could restructure your input perhaps?  After profiling of course.

Comment: Just re-read the question - this is data that the user types in?  Then why allow them the chance to give contradictory information, like:
"3"
"1 2"

Answer (score 0):

You might experiment with [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), but if you know what delimiter is being used ahead of time, just use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This works just fine. In fact, this is faster than the StringTokenizer method. Thanks @yock

Answer (score 0):

```
new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[ ]")
```

should help you avoid the problem noted by Vanathi in his answer. As for knowing the size of your array, something like :

```
br.readLine().split("[ ]").length;
```

should do it.

Comment: Damn, my regex are rusty. Could very well work with just an empty space between brackets, can't test it right now.